# Why do relational databases only accept SQL queries?

Tags: database, sql

As far as I know, most relational databases do not offer any driver-level API for queries, except a `query` function which takes an SQL string as an argument.

I'm thinking how easier it would be if one could do:

```
var result = mysql.select('article', {id: 3})
```

For joined tables, it would be slightly more complex, but still possible. For example:

```
var tables = mysql.join({tables: ['article', 'category'], on: 'categoryID'});
mysql.select(tables, {'article.id': 3}, ['article.title', 'article.body', 'category.categoryID'])
```

Cleaner code, no string parsing overhead, no injection problems, easier reuse of query elements... I can see a lot of advantages.

Is there a specific reason why it was chosen to only provide access to queries through SQL?

Comment: What does your first example do that an ORM doesn't already provide?

Comment: Your way would work just fine if the only thing anyone ever did was simple queries.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nothing. But it needs to be converted to SQL. The point of my question is why can't we have driver-level access to data manipulation operations.

Comment: I would like to see a complex query with that sintaxys.

Comment: If you are doing string parsing/replacement in your SQL strings. Then you are doing it wrong. You should be binding arguments to a prepared statement object.

Comment: Interestingly, there are some imperative languages—Cobol against DB2, C against Sybase, to name a couple that I know of—that actually support (or used to support) embedded SQL statements. Not as strings, but actually embedded as code, and probably pre-processed out and compiled separately. I can't think of a modern example, but it's not unheard of to have your application code at least appear to operate on database constructs directly.

Comment: To me this is like asking why don't toasters accept Ice cream.

Comment: Someone already thought of what you're thinking and took it a step further and thus ORM's were born.

Comment: I suspect that there is some unusual history at work here ... the first entrant in the field (relational DB as opposed to the less mathematically founded ones that preceded it) came with a well developed theory and a fairly (very?) complete set of operators, making it so much better than the competition that no one ever bothered to offer a different language for expressing relational operations.

Comment: @lortabac to answer "why can't we have driver-level access" - at this point, for most RDBMSes, SQL *is* the lowest level that is feasible to expose.  E.g. query plans typically get cached based on slightly modified SQL strings, so it's deeply embedded in the engine itself.  At the end of the day, the cost of parsing on the server is not that great (effectively constant time regardless of data size), and if you want strong typing / code reuse, there are plenty of SQL builders or ORMs out there which do just that.

Comment: @lortabac - So, given your hypothetical syntax, how would you write up `select * from Carts where TotalSpent > 900 and Status IN (2, 6)`?  In SQL, that's very easy to see exactly what it's going to get - what about in yours?

Comment: I like this question. Although the answers given are correct (SQL is a standards, etc) I would much rather have a functional language that used a different syntax than SQL...

Comment: If you take a look at LINQ to Entities for .NET, it has a syntax that is very similar to what you are proposing.  It is a .NET-specific API for accessing databases, which is translated to standards-based SQL behind the scenes.  So in a certain sense you get the best of both worlds.  I imagine that similar technologies could exist (or already exist) for other languages.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

Comment: @HLGEM Uhh I think you may be confusing a toaster with a freezer there.

Comment: @Bobson `from('Carts').select('*').whereGreater('TotalSpent', 900).whereIn('Status', [ 2, 6 ])` or something along those lines, perhaps

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Databases are out of process - they run on a different server usually. So even if you had an API, it would need to send something across the wire that represents your query and all of its projections, filters, groups, subqueries, expressions, joins, aggregate functions etc. That something could be XML or JSON or some proprietary format, but it may as well be SQL because that is tried, tested and supported.

It is less common these days to build up SQL commands yourself - many people use some sort of ORM. Even though these ultimately translate into SQL statements, they may provide the API you are after.

Comment: I disagree about building SQL commands by hand. ORM are fine for very simplistic data models. Anything beyond trivial you are writing your own SQL layer.

Comment: I'll play devils advocate and note than any reasonable ORM should be configurable to meet the needs of an application.

Comment: @LokiAstari: True, but the trivial CRUD stuff can make up 80% or more of your application.

Comment: @Tim, excellent point. In fact, the hypothetical syntax proposed in the question looks an awful lot like JSON.

Comment: JSON is a data encapsulation and transfer format, not a language.

Comment: @JohnMGant It's actually resemblant of JavaScript, which JSON was built for and is very similar to.

Comment: @Craig See comment above.

Comment: So your argument is basically, "We already use SQL; might as well keep using it!" What?

Answer (score 35):

Because SQL provides a common API.  You can write an ANSI 92 SQL compliant driver that emits SQL and exposes the API you desire. As a special bonus, it will work with almost any SQL database without rewriting.

If it was done your way, every SQL database would have a different API.  Unless, of course, we all standardized on your API.  But then, we'd have SQL again, more or less, wouldn't we?  Except that your API appears to be programming language-specific, whereas SQL is not.

Comment: "Everyone uses this same language, so we should always continue to use this language until the end of time, because if we switched to other languages, then we would all have to use different languages!"

Comment: Not sure the point you were trying to make here.  Perhaps you could read the story about the Tower of Babel?

Comment: I'm very familiar with it. But clearly some languages are superior to others.

Comment: Ah, so you were trying to make a joke.  Fair point, well-played.

Answer (score 7):

There's more to do on the database for administrative purposes, so being able to script and submit text to add users, run backups, load data, change the schema etc. is important. Most DBA's won't want to do this inside some other programming language.

If DBA's want to hang on to SQL, you have to have another language, the database would have the burden of processing both.

There are many new features in databases, so I don't think they're getting stagnant. They're just not doing what you propose for some reason.

SQL Server has the ability to execute .NET code from the inside through SQL CLR. This is helpful for some of those tasks that don't fit into a relational model, but want to maintain performance. I realize this isn't what you're looking for. It's an example of the many things databases are doing.

It's not going to go away any time soon. One of the more recent databases to hit the market is [NuoDB](http://www.nuodb.com). They kept SQL, provide ACID while adding the ability to distribute servers and run it in a cloud. You may want to look into why they went to all that trouble to promote the continuation of SQL (Not their only reason, but it's a huge selling point.).

Comment: .NET code in SQL Server doesn't actually run inside the database engine. It's .NET code compiled to an assembly on the server and the stored procedures are attributed static class methods that the database server knows how to call. The methods use a data provider and make a connection to the database like any other .NET code. You have a similar situation with databases (Oracle, Sybase) which support Java stored procedures. SQL, on the other hand, is the "native interface" of the database, is similar across most database products and actually is parsed and executed directly in the database.

Comment: @Craig - Excellent point.

Answer (score 3):

SQL DBMS provide substantially optimised access to the store through the native language and many, as you note provide no other API.

The observation that the database is out of process does not apply in a number of cases and is not really directly relevant.

Even databases that require the use of the SQL DML often provide a cursor library to provide iterator access to a result set, and the well known Microsoft Access and Btrieve SQL DBMS both provide a direct record interface to the individual tables in a database as a mechanism for very high performance access under specific circumstances.

As noted, complex queries using such a syntax would reproduce the behaviour of network databases from the late '70s.

The alternate access mechanisms are less attractive to the mainstream users due to the unfamiliarity, but the growth in popularity of the NoSQL databases could increase interest in other APIs to achieve specific performance gains. There seems little else to recommend such an approach.